# Asp.Net Core 2 Authentication not work without browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity

I have problem with authentication in asp.net Core 2

When I use web browser (that start with visual studio debugging mode )

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

Worked without problem but when I try to use this API from another domain or Postman (Chrome Extension)

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

Is always false!

This is my log in code:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("user","pass",true,false);
```

This is my startup.cs

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add database
        services.AddDbContext<CoreDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
            options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
        }
        );
        // add sign in manager
        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

            // Lockout settings
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;

            // User settings
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CoreDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        services.AddCors();

        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        });
        services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options => options.Level = System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        services.AddResponseCompression();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {


        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        DbOption.Option = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CoreDbContext>();
        DbOption.Option.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
        DbOption.Option.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);

        app.UseResponseCompression();
        app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://192.168.30.100:91", "OtherDomain.com")
            .AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

When I use web browser all things work without any problem.
I think this is for cookie proble.

Comment: "from another domain" what do you mean by this? Also, Postman doesn't use cookies so it won't work.

Comment: Like Camilo said, Identity relies on a cookie. If your client doesn't store the cookie that is set in the login method and add it to the header of each additional request, `IsAuthenticated` will always be false because of the missing cookie.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I used postman for .net core 1 and working without problem. Postman support cookie

Comment: @NightOwl888 This is not work by browser if I use as API

Comment: there is a cookies tab on postman that displays all cookies in use. Not sure what you mean by it doesn't use cookies

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do from the other domain? do you want to share cookies between the websites?

Comment: @NightOwl888 I use this code in my old project and there is no problem but when I update .net core 1.2 to 2 this code not work. Do I need add anything? Like cookie manager ?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane  I use this code in my old project and there is no problem but when I update .net core 1.2 to 2 this code not work. Do I need add anything? Like cookie manager ?

Comment: @NightOwl888 My web api project is separated from client. My client is written by AgularJS4 in other domain and I use http request between them. I used this method in my old project till .net core 2 the problem started from .net core 2

Comment: well core 2 does have `services.AddAuthentication.AddCookie()` you could. Never used it with identity so i am not sure if you really need it.